# (ADD mousewheel functionality) using DOMmouseScroll AND mousewheel to call functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, mousewheel

I'm trying to make a function that calls other functions when the mousewheel moves in different directions. I don't have any idea as to how to implement this

I originally set up the code to be able to work with the mousewheel event, but Firefox doesn't support the mouswheel event. So I need a way to do it with DOMmouseScroll as well. If anyone could I'd like it to be set up in a similar way that I already set it up.

**NOTE: I am asking for both DOMmouseScroll and mousewheel to be used, so I suggest adding to my code, but if it can't be done that way, it'll be fine...**

Here is the way I set up the code:

```
$( '#container' ).on( 'mousewheel', function ( event ) {

    // crude check to see events are supported
    if ( typeof event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaX === 'undefined'
        || typeof event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY === 'undefined' ) {
        console.log( "could not find mouse deltas" );
        return;
    }

    var deltaX = event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaX;
    var deltaY = event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY;

    var scrolledLeft = deltaX < 0;
    var scrolledRight = deltaX > 0;
    var scrolledUp = deltaY < 0;
    var scrolledDown = deltaY > 0;

    if ( scrolledLeft ) { someFunction }
    if ( scrolledRight ) { someOtherFunction }
    if ( scrolledUp ) { anotherFunction }
    if ( scrolledDown ) { andAnotherFunction }
});
```

Comment: A question should be abstracted from dependencies. All relevant code should be posted here -- not linked to. As of right now this simply looks like a duplicate question -- you should edit your original to try and figure out a cross browser compatible answer.

Comment: @SterlingArcher To be honest, I'd actually like to see the answer to this question, since adding input from the scrolling wheel can make the webpage that much more interactive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest re-implementing this using the cross-browser-compatible [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event instead. mousescroll and DOMmousescroll have been deprecated in favor of this new event in modern browsers. Please read all of the documentation on that page for the details as well as an example implementation of a cross-browser-compatible `addWheelListener` function.

Comment: So long have I waited for an answer